# I am trying to insert a php variable to mysql but, it automatically inserts 0 instead of the value of the variable

Tags: php, mysql, insert, sql-insert

I am trying to insert a php variable to mysql but, it automatically inserts 0 instead of the value of the variable.

```
    <?php 
    $username_view = $_GET['user'];
    $current_user = getUserIdFromUsername($username_view);
    $current_user_chat = (int)$current_user;

    // echo gettype($current_user_chat);

    echo var_dump($current_user_chat); //echos original value

    if (isset($_POST['send_message_button_btn'])) {
        $message_text_txt=sanitizeString($_POST['send_message_text_txt']);
        $user_logged_in= $_SESSION['user_id'];
        queryMysql("INSERT INTO messages (message_sender_id, message_receiver_id, message_text, messege_date, message_time) VALUES ('$user_logged_in', $current_user_chat, '$message_text_txt', CURDATE(), CURTIME())");
        echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'> alert('sent');</script>";
        header("Location: user_home.php");
    }

?>
```

The value of the variable `$current_user_chat` is stored as '0'. 
When I echo the value of `var_dump($current_user)` is printed as expected.

The function `getUserIdFromUsername($username_view)` is:

```
<?php
function getUserIdFromUsername($username){
    $result = queryMysql("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username ='$username' ");
    $row = getRows($result);
    if($row){
        return $row['user_id'];
    }
    else{
        echo "<script type= text/javascript> alert('No such Users') </script>";
    }
?>
```

Here is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="messages.php?user=$username_view" class="chat-form">
   <textarea name="send_message_text_txt"></textarea>
   <button name="send_message_button_btn" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
</form>
```

When the SQL query is echoed it is as:

```
INSERT INTO messages (message_sender_id, message_receiver_id, message_text, messege_date, message_time) VALUES ('1', 5, '', CURDATE(), CURTIME())
```

Comment: What data type is that column in your database? Your column names indicate they are expecting to hold integers and not strings. You also specifically cast that value to an int on line 3, so...

Comment: No - don't do this. Please read - https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/296555

Comment: Since you're not using prepared statements, echo out that query and verify the data that you're pushing. Then double-check the data type of the column. You really ought to use prepared statements and parameter binding to prevent quoting issues and sql injection.

Comment: Here is the Table Structure: CREATE TABLE messages(
 message_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
 message_sender_id BIGINT(11) NOT NULL,
 message_receiver_id BIGINT(11) NOT NULL,
 message_text TEXT NOT NULL,
 messege_date DATE NOT NULL,
 message_time TIME NOT NULL
 );

Comment: What is the value of `$current_user_chat`?

Comment: The data type of message_receiver_id is BIGINT(11). When echoed using: gettype($current_user_chat);
echo var_dump($current_user_chat);   type is printed as integer along with the actual expected value.

Comment: The value of $current_user_chat is obtained as:

http://localhost/social/messages.php?user=akash

$username_view = $_GET['user'];
$current_user = getUserIdFromUsername($username_view);
$current_user_chat = (int)$current_user;

Comment: Echo your full query. What do you get?

Comment: Can you show the form i have a feeling you don't send the user param in the url when saving. You are using $_GET and $_POST there.

Comment: INSERT INTO messages (message_sender_id, message_receiver_id, message_text, messege_date, message_time) VALUES ('1', 5, '', CURDATE(), CURTIME())

The message_receiver_id is 5 which is as according to the username.

Comment: Yep, that's a head scratcher, then. Try using that string to insert directly into the database, and see if it throws any warnings.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have added the form code in the post. Do have a look at it.

Comment: @aynber Passing the string directly doesn't throw any error. Still 0 is inserted.

Comment: To add to @anyber comment manually select the warnings if anny with SHOW WARNINGS; after running the insert.. no error does not always mean there are no warnings

Comment: @JohnConde So what?

Comment: Can you pls show us the source of `queryMysql` and also `sanitizeString`? In addition, please show the output of `var_dump($current_user_chat);` when used **directly inside** `if (isset($_POST...`. I am trying to rule out `$_GET`/`$_POST` issues. Update your question with these; don't post them in the comments. And again, I can't stress enough, don't use variables inside your query - use parameterized queries (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). It will solve a lot of your problems.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for the suggestion about form.I made a change in the action and now it is working fine.

Comment: @waterloomatt Thank you for the response. There was a problem with the form action. It's fine now.

Comment: Well i geuss i need some caffaine badly i totally overlooked the `action="messages.php?user=$username_view"` didn't use `<?php echo ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem in the form action.

```
<form method="post" action="messages.php?user=$username_view" class="chat-form">
   <textarea name="send_message_text_txt"></textarea>
   <button name="send_message_button_btn" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
</form>
```

The variables were actually not being passed. I echoed the parameter instead of writing it directly in the form action.

The new form code is:

```
<form method="post" action="messages.php?user=<?php echo $username_view ?>" class="chat-form">
    <textarea name="send_message_text_txt"></textarea>
    <button name="send_message_button_btn" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Doh! We should have caught that.

Comment: Wait - you showed us your `INSERT` statement where `5` was being passed. How is that possible?

Comment: Well i geuss i need some caffaine badly i totally overlooked the `action="messages.php?user=$username_view"` didn't use `<?php echo ?>`.. lucky iam not the only one.

Comment: @waterloomatt I really don't know about that. I'm also surprised.

Comment: @RaymondNijland HaHa! No problem.

Answer (score -1):

Probably the column `message_sender_id` is an int, and in the query you try to input the value with quotation marks

Comment: I tried to do it with and without quotes. It didn't worked.

Comment: Can you post what that sql echoes?

Comment: What's the data type of the `message_receiver_id` on the table?

Comment: It is BIGINT. I found the errors. Thank you for the response.